# What statement can be made about $A^{-T}A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, transpose

Given a matrix $A$ and the transpose of its inverse, $A^{-T}$, are there any useful properties of their product $A^{-T}A$? The only thing that came to my mind was

$$\det(A^{-T}A) = \underbrace{\det(A^{-T})}_{=(\det A)^{-1}}\det A = 1$$

Are there any other statements that can be made about e.g. the trace or eigenvalues of this product? What about their commutator $[A^{-T},A]$?

Comment: It is interestingly reminiscent of the expression 
$$
U = (AA^T)^{-1/2}A
$$
which is the orthogonal matrix from the polar decomposition $A = PU$.  $U$ is also the [nearest orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) to $A$.  Nevertheless, my suspicion is that we can't say much.

Comment: One observation: suppose that $A$ is invertible and that $A = P_1U$ and $A = UP_2$ are polar-decompositions of $A$ (as it turns out, it can be shown that the same $U$ works in both equations).  We have
$$
A^{-T}A = (P_1U)^{-T}(UP_2) = P_1^{-1}UUP_2 = P_1^{-1} U^2 P_2.
$$
If $A$ is normal (i.e. $A^TA = AA^T$) then $P_1 = P_2$ and the above shows that $A$ is similar to $U^2$.  In other words, if $A$ is normal, then we can guarantee that $A^{-T}A$ has eigenvalues with magnitude $1$.

Comment: For the above two comments, I assume that we are discussing only matrices with real entries.  For complex matrices, the transpose would have to be replaced with a conjugate-transpose in order for the above to apply.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Interesting observation, thanks!